# Additional Parameter when Add items to cart

Tags: magento-1.8, quote

I'm needing to save an additional parameter when the customer click in "addToCart". In the product page I added a box with some data to fill. When the customer click on "addToCart" these data should be saved in a column created in **sales_flat_quote_item** called "passengers_data". But I can't save in my custom column.

I've created a Event to catch the custom parameters. 
Here is my config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <DevXIII_CpfPlus>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </DevXIII_CpfPlus>
    </modules>

    <global>

        <models>
            <cpfplus>
                <class>DevXIII_CpfPlus_Model</class>
            </cpfplus>
        </models>


        <events>
            <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
                <observers>
                    <cpfplus>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>cpfplus/observer</class>
                        <method>convertPassengers</method>
                    </cpfplus>
                </observers>
            </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
        </events> 

        <resources>
            <cpfplus_setup>

                <setup>
                    <module>DevXIII_CpfPlus</module>
                    <class>DevXIII_CpfPlus_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>directory_setup</use>
                </connection>

            </cpfplus_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>

    <frontend>

        <!-- Begin: Sobrescrevendo o controller do checkout -->
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <DevXIII_CpfPlus before="Mage_Checkout">DevXIII_CpfPlus</DevXIII_CpfPlus>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
        <!-- End: Sobrescrevendo o controller do checkout -->

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <cpfplus>
                    <file>cpfplus.xml</file>
                </cpfplus>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

And here is my Model/Observer.php:

```
<?php

class DevXIII_CpfPlus_Model_Observer
{

    public function convertPassengers( $observer )
    {
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        $params = $observer->getRequest()->getParams();

    }

}
```

The idea is save these data to display for each product saved in order, but I don't know how I can do this.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well, you only use getters. You should call `setPassengerData()` on the quote item. Then the question remains if you have the right event. I think this is dispatched after `save()`, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I made a test and it saves after save()... the variable $item is empty( I used print_r() ). So I need to dispatch before save() aaand, with my custom data.

Comment: Have you achieved this functionality ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That event doesn't have the quote item. In 1.8.0.0:

```
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
            array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
        );
```

It isn't in there. You want the `checkout_cart_product_add_after` event. For two reasons:

1. It has a quote item
2. It's called before the cart->save() in the `checkout_cart_add_product_complete` event.

So your event XML should be:

```
        <checkout_cart_product_add_after>
            <observers>
                <cpfplus>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>cpfplus/observer</class>
                    <method>convertPassengers</method>
                </cpfplus>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

And your observer handler:

```
public function convertPassengers( $observer )
{
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $params = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParams();

    $item->setPassengerData($this->doSomethingWith($params));
}
```